# Android PHP pass Session Variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am programming an app and have a problem. My problem is that when I save a Session Variable I can't use it in another PHP Script because it seems like that it didn't save the variable.

In my App I have a Login Activity. After the Teacher has logged in a bunch of Students should be shown in a ListView. But the listview shows no Students and that is because the php script doesn't pass the variable.

I will post my Script below. I hope you can help me. Is so difficult because I call everything from the app?

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];   

    if($username == '' || $password == ''){
        echo '';
    }else{
        require_once('dbConnect.php');
        $sql = "select * from T_Teacher where username='$username' and password='$password'";
        mysqli_error($con);
        $result= mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql));                    
    }
    if(isset($result)){
        echo "success";
        $_SESSION['ID_Teacher'] = $result['ID_Teacher'];

    }else{

        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    }else{
        echo "Try again!";
    }
?>
```

get_list.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT T_Student.ID_Student, T_Student.Name, T_Student.Surname, T_Teacher.ID_Teacher 
FROM T_Student,T_Teacher  WHERE  T_Student.F_ID_Teacher = .$_SESSION['ID_Arzt'] ";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))  
{  
    $output[] = $row;

}
print json_encode($output);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Side note: this is a manual example of SQL injection.

Comment: If you don't have a proper debugger for your environment, can't you just use a browser? It's HTTP after all.